# Docker daemon config file on boot2docker / docker-machine / Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

Where can I find docker daemon config file on boot2docker machine?

According to this topic: [Dockerfile: Docker build can't download packages: centos->yum, debian/ubuntu->apt-get behind intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130536/dockerfile-docker-build-cant-download-packages-centos-yum-debian-ubuntu-ap)

I want to set '--dns' in `DOCKER_OPTS`, but I can't find this config file either at `/etc/default` or anywhere else.

Comment: Hello @anaid. Did we resolve your question? If so please mark the correct answer. If not, how we can help you?

Answer (score 58):

Inside boot2docker (`boot2docker ssh`) / docker-machine (`docker-machine ssh default`) , open or create the file **/var/lib/boot2docker/profile** and add the following line:

```
EXTRA_ARGS="--dns 192.168.1.145"
```

Also works for:

```
EXTRA_ARGS="--insecure-registry myinternaldocker"
```

After the change you need to restart the docker daemon:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

Or leave boot2docker / docker-machine and restart the entire virtual machine:

```
boot2docker restart
# for docker machine
docker-machine restart default
```

Information taken from: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/docker-user/04pAX57WQ7g/_LI-z8iknxYJ

Comment: And that link leads to: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md

Comment: This works, but I had to run "boot2docker down; boot2docker up" to get the changes to take effect

Comment: @David you can use "sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart" as well and is faster. I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 12):

If you are using a mac you have to go to a fresh terminal and run:

```
boot2docker ssh
```

This will open a new terminal, from there you have to edit or create a file

```
sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

and add the DNS that you would like to add, for example:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4"
```

After that you need to restart boot2docker. Here I had some issues at the beginning so I close everything and run in a terminal:

```
boot2docker down
boot2docker up
```

you can also use:

```
boot2docker restart
```

I had to do it twice. After that I started again using the normal boot2docker icon and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to script things, you can do these steps on one ugly line:

```
boot2docker ssh 'sudo sh -c "echo \"EXTRA_ARGS=\\\"--dns 1.2.3.4\\\"\" > /var/lib/boot2docker/profile && sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart"'
```