# Using docker on Mac. Is it possible to start docker daemon using docker-machine and pass in arguments?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-registry

I have a private repo that I need to pass in via the "--insecure-registry myprivateregistry:5000" argument that works fine in my linux environment via this command:

docker -d --insecure-registry myprivateregistry:5000

I'm not sure how to pass this is when I'm starting my MAC client however. I use docker-machine to start and stop my default instance, but I don't see how to pass in that option. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I need to add that as an extra argument in this file after I do a **docker-machine ssh default** (my running daemon):

```
/var/lib/boot2docker/profile 

EXTRA_ARGS='--insecure-registry myprivateregistry:5000'
```

Restart the docker daemon via **docker-machine restart default** and now I can connect!

This article was useful: [Docker daemon config file on boot2docker / docker-machine / Docker Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424338/docker-daemon-config-file-on-boot2docker)