# Change Docker's images/containers path

Tags: docker

How can I change the path that Docker uses to store images/containers?

I'm aware that this can be done editing Docker's daemon config file, but I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan, so that doesn't apply (or does it?).

I'm using Docker 1.12

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26424338/1005215

Comment: @NehalJWani I'm not using boot2docker. I clearly specified I'm on Docker 1.12

Comment: Are you using docker-machine ?

Comment: No. I'm using Docker native (the one and only feature I'm actually using 1.12).

Comment: AFAIK, they use xhyve instead of virtualbox in docker 1.12 otherwise it works same as before.