# Enable Docker remote API in Mac (Using Docker Quickstart Terminal)

Tags: macos, docker

**NOTE : I am not using boot2docker**

I am trying to enable the docker remote API on my mac. However all the question here are based on using `boot2docker`. While installing docker on my machine, I followed [these steps using the Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/mac/step_one/) and since then I have always used the command `bash --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'` to start docker in my local machine.

I was trying to follow the [steps mentioned here](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/07/quick-tip-how-to-enable-docker-remote-api.html), which state that I have to edit the `docker.conf` file. However I cannot locate the file at all. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your remote API should already be available. `docker-machine env default` will give you the details.

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.56.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/jimbob/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

In the end they both use a VirtualBox VM running boot2docker, they are just accessed in different ways.

Any [daemon configuration can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26781047) in the `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` file if needed.