# How to enable the Docker Remote API on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, tcp, boot2docker

I am trying to use the Docker Remote API on a Windows 10 host machine. I am using Chrome's Postman extension to see if I can get results from the docker remote api's endpoints. Here are the endpoints that I've tried:

`GET http://192.168.99.100:4243/images/json`

`GET http://192.168.99.100:2376/images/json`

Both returned `Connection to server 192.168.99.100 failed (The server is not responding)`

After a few searches I found out that the Docker Remote API is not enabled by default on Windows. Most of the guides are for Ubuntu but I have found this particular [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294853/how-to-enable-docker-api-access-from-windows-running-docker-toolbox-docker-mach) for Windows.

These are the steps that I performed on my machine

1. docker-machine ssh
2. cd /var/lib/boot2docker
3. sudo vi profile
4. Change `DOCKER_HOST='H tcp://0.0.0.2376'` to `DOCKER_HOST='H tcp://0.0.0.2375'`
5. change `DOCKER_TLS=auto` to `DOCKER_TLS=no`
6. export DOCKER_HOST='-H tcp://0.0.0.2375'
7. export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0
8. env | grep DOCKER
9. docker-machine restart
10. docker-machine env
11. docker-machine regenerate-certs

After performing the steps above, I did try again the endpoints on Postman but I still get the same result.

Can you perhaps give a little help if I have missed a step? Or am I on track?

Also, to answer some of my queries.

1. Is the docker remote api port for Windows 2375 and 4243 for Linux?
2. Is DOCKER_HOST for Windows and DOCKER_OPTS for Linux?

Comment: facing same issue ,please help us

Answer (score 9):

Switch your docker to `windows container`

Got to `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config`
in `deamon.json` file

add `"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2376", "npipe://"]`

restart docker.

give command : `docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 ps`

Comment: On Windows Server 2016, replaced 2376 with 2375 and it worked!

Comment: Using Windows 11 and Docker for Windows 4.19, I have no `docker` directory under `C:\programData`. Also, what is "windows container"?

Answer (score 0):

The Remote API is now enabled by default on Windows (see [ticket here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32733#u=1470082504230)).

It is reachable at `http:\\localhost:2375` indeed (tested it).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found a quick solution for this. Just open docker settings and enable "Expose daemon on TCP..." checkbox. Docker will start automatically and the problem should be solved.[Please find the image attached for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GsOv.png)

Answer (score 0):

using docker desktop, go to settings and check "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS"