# run docker on a remote windows server from a non windows box

Tags: windows, macos, docker

the laptops I use are mac or linux.

But I also work with windows containers.

These containers are very large so using them on a windows VM is a pain because it uses up lots of disk space.

Is there some way of connecting to a remote windows docker host from mac or linux in a more seamless way? So I can run docker commands against a dockerfile locally but it executes on a remote windows server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable remote access to Docker API on your remote host ([Windows system in your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398321/how-to-enable-the-docker-remote-api-on-windows)). You may need to enable also auth to be safe.

Then just configure env variable which will point your local docker client to remote API (remote docker daemon), for example:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<IP>:<PORT>
```

See doc for more details about env variables. There is env variable also for auth (DOCKER_CERT_PATH): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables

This approach works with Docker API and all files, which you are using in the container/in build process from host OS must be available also on the remote machine.

Comment: That's works with cli commands? If I run docker build how does the dockerfile and other files get from my PC to the remote docker host?

Comment: Yes, that works with docker command in CLI. And no, it didn't synchronize your files from your local host to the remote machine = you need to copy Dockerfile to Windows machine, but then you will be able to run build from Mac.  You need a different approach for the file sync. Maybe NFS RW mount to your local Mac.