# Docker API access from the network

Tags: api, docker, networking, daemon

I use Docker (Toolbox) on Windows 7.
I would like to access the docker daemon by the remote api from other computers.

My computer ip is: 192.168.140.150

By default the docker daemon accessible the following mode:

Ex: **curl ... https://192.168.99.150:2376/images/json**

but the 192.168.99.... is not a public network (it is created by docker). I can access it only from my computer.

I would like to access docker api the following mode: 

Ex: **curl ... https://192.168.140.150:2376/images/json**

or
**curl http://192.168.140.150:2375/images/json**

and not only from my computer (so I want to skip certificate parameters from the curl command too)

Important! Windows 7 and Docker Toolbox with Virtual Box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Docker API access from Windows running Docker Toolbox (docker machine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294853/how-to-enable-docker-api-access-from-windows-running-docker-toolbox-docker-mach)

Comment: Just remember that anyone who can access the Docker API has unrestricted root access over the host; in Docker Toolbox it's slightly limited to that VM, but you've probably given the VM read/write access over all of your user directory.

Comment: Yes it is a solution but not complete because in this case you can access docker commands only if you login into the docker machine with ssh.