# Pass --net=host to docker build

Tags: docker

To pass other options to `docker build`, you can speciy `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker`, however --net is not available. Is it possible to use the host's networking stack when building a container?

I'm running Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to use my hosts networking stack when building containers. I have trouble getting a docker container to use my company's intranet's dns server at build time. Using --net=host was the easiest way to get it working when running a container.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To solve the problem, configure docker daemon to use the your company DNS server. For instance, if your resolv.conf has the following configuration:

```
$> cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain mycompany
search mycompany
nameserver 10.123.123.123
```

Change /etc/default/docker to contain the following:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 10.123.123.123"
```

And restart docker daemon with:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Now, containers will have access to the intranet during the build operation.

Related answer: [Dockerfile: Docker build can't download packages: centos->yum, debian/ubuntu->apt-get behind intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130606/1068411)

Comment: I also had to remove private DNS as in (http://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away)
BONUS oneliner: DOCKER_OPTS=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ printf " --dns " $2 }') && sudo service docker restart

Comment: And to find your DNS ip in windows use ipconfig /all | findstr /R "DNS\ Servers"
originally https://superuser.com/a/486925

Answer (score 35):

Try `--network` instead of `--net`. It is new in the 1.25 API and [sets the networking mode for the RUN instructions](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options).

Comment: I tried Sergey's answer .. that and only that didn't work ... then I tried this on top of it ... worked !

Answer (score 11):

From the newest versions (currently docker ce v17) it is possible to add --network=host to your docker build command which is similar to --net=host when using docker run!