# docker build fails on a cloud VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu, docker, cloud, containers

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) running inside an Azure VM. I have followed the instructions to install Docker and all seems fine and dandy.

One of the things that I need to do when I trigger `docker run` is to pass `--net=host`, which allows me to run `apt-get update` and other internet-dependent commands within the container.

The problem comes in when I try to trigger `docker build` based on an existing Ubuntu image. It fails:

[image]

The problem here is that there is no way to pass `--net=host` to the build command. I see that there are issues open on the Docker GitHub ([#20987](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20987), [#10324](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10324)) but no clear resolution.

There is an [existing answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435479/pass-net-host-to-docker-build) that covers the scenario I want, but that doesn't work within a cloud VM.

Any thoughts on what might be happening?

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the `docker version` output:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 22:11:10 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 22:11:10 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the output from `docker network ls`:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
aa69fa066700        bridge              bridge              local               
1bd082a62ab3        host                host                local               
629eacc3b77e        none                null                local
```

Comment: apt-get should still work using the default bridged network unless your network requires use of a proxy server or has firewall rules preventing NATed traffic. What happens if you try to run ping or curl in a container using the bridged network?

Comment: Both `ping` and `curl` work directly on the VM. `docker build` still fails.

Comment: Do they work in the container? The VM is using the host network, but containers use the bridged network.

Comment: Here is the trick, like described above - when I do `docker run`, I can pass `--net=host` and then `ping`, `apt-get` and `curl` will work. There is no way to  pass `--net=host` to `docker build` which results in failure.

Comment: What I'm saying is by default using the bridged network those should still work. Finding out why those don't work may help you find a way to fix the issue.

Comment: Any way to diagnose that?

Comment: docker run -it --rm busybox (or ubuntu) should create a container with an interactive shell

Comment: Under azure, you created a ubunut VM and inside that, you are running a docker-machine setup, right? Use `docker run -i -t ubuntu bash` and then check what `cat /etc/resolv.conf` gives you. What happens on `nslookup google` and what happens on `ping 8.8.8.8` ?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to try letting docker-machine provision the VM for you and see if that works. There is a [provider for Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/docker-machine-azure-driver/), so you should be able to set your subscription id on a local Docker client (Windows or Linux) and [follow the instructions](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/azure/) to get a new VM provisioned with Docker and it will also setup your local environment variables to communicate with the Docker VM instance remotely. After it is setup running `docker ps` or `docker run` locally would run the commands as if you were running them on the VM. Example:

```
#Name at end should be all lower case or it will fail.
docker-machine create --driver azure --azure-subscription-id <omitted> --azure-image canonical:ubuntuserver:16.04.0-LTS:16.04.201608150 --azure-size Standard_A0 azureubuntu
#Partial output, see docker-machine resource group in Azure portal
Running pre-create checks...
(azureubuntu) Completed machine pre-create checks.
Creating machine...
(azureubuntu) Querying existing resource group.  name="docker-machine"
(azureubuntu) Resource group "docker-machine" already exists.
(azureubuntu) Configuring availability set.  name="docker-machine"
(azureubuntu) Configuring network security group.  location="westus" name="azureubuntu-firewall"
(azureubuntu) Querying if virtual network already exists.  name="docker-machine-vnet" location="westus"
(azureubuntu) Configuring subnet.  vnet="docker-machine-vnet" cidr="192.168.0.0/16" name="docker-machine"
(azureubuntu) Creating public IP address.  name="azureubuntu-ip" static=false
(azureubuntu) Creating network interface.  name="azureubuntu-nic"
(azureubuntu) Creating virtual machine.  osImage="canonical:ubuntuserver:16.04.0-LTS:16.04.201608150" name="azureubuntu" location="westus" size="Standard_A0" username="docker-user"
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env azureubuntu

#Set environment using PowerShell (or login to the new VM) and see containers on remote host
docker-machine env azureubuntu | Invoke-Expression
docker info
docker network inspect bridge

#Build a local docker project using the remote VM
docker build MyProject
docker images

#To clean up the Azure resources for a machine (you can create multiple, also check docker-machine resource group in Azure portal)
docker-machine rm azureubuntu
```

Best I can tell that is working fine. I was able to build a debian:wheezy DockerFile that uses apt-get on the Azure VM without any issues. This should allow the containers to run using the default bridged network as well instead of the host network.

Comment: I will try doing that and see what results it will output. I configured the DNS settings according to VM configuration, so not sure what might be causing failures.

Answer (score 0):

According to [I can't get Docker containers to access the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810845/i-cant-get-docker-containers-to-access-the-internet) using `sudo systemctl restart docker` might help, or enable [net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/311054/266909) or [disable the firewall](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-server-disable-firewall/).

Also you may need to [update the dns servers](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1809#issuecomment-24080655) in /etc/resolv.conf on the VM

Comment: Just like the original poster for that question, already all of these items are tackled and unfortunately have no effect. `--net=host` works when I do `docker run` so that's awesome, would work for me. It's `docker build` that fails.

Comment: The issue you are seeing indicates that your bridge network can't reach the outside world, which will probably cause other issues in the future. If you don't plan on using the bridge network in docker you could try deleting it with `docker network rm`, but network isolation is a big part of why people usually use docker containers. Hence the reason why the --net=host parameter may not be available for all docker commands.

Comment: For diagnostic purposes, updated the main post with the output of `docker network ls`.

Comment: yeah... that is all pretty vanilla. The issue is likely somewhere in sysctl or the VM's DNS setup. I'll try spinning up an Azure VM using docker-machine and see if it works there.

Comment: Stupid question, but can you reach anything in internet with desired protocols from this VM? My expirience with Azure Firewalls was that is not always working like one may asume it..