# Docker hello-world on Ubuntu - permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to get docker (v 1.8.2) to work on Ubuntu 14_04, (using the -g option in the docker config file - Ubuntu is on a USB key and I got errors pulling images without using the disk of the machine). The result is that docker pulls the hello-world image but execution fails because of permissions.  Any idea why and what I can do to fix it?

Here's the command and the result:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
535020c3e8ad: Pull complete 
af340544ed62: Pull complete 
library/hello-world:latest: The image you are pulling has been verified. Important: image verification is a tech preview feature and should not be relied on to provide security.
Digest: sha256:02fee8c3220ba806531f606525eceb83f4feb654f62b207191b1c9209188dedd
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
exec: "/hello": permission denied
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container d16115c24bfdf2183a2f5e9abe2c570b85e9edd01f957dbed5f7a084680e42b5: [8] System error: exec: "/hello": permission denied
```

BTW, I've been trying for days to get docker installed and running on linux (I switched to Ubuntu 14_04 after giving up on Mint 17 - this after getting boot2docker on Windows 7 up and working in 5 min. on the same machine and network) booting off a USB key. I've given up on trying to store the docker files on the key itself (I get aufs mount errors when I pull, when the pull actually gets that far).  So now I'm just trying to get docker working in some configuration.

**Update:**

I've tried a few things.  I tried using chmods to add permissions to the docker storage dir.  Now the image fails to load with the following:

```
Error response from daemon: error creating aufs mount to /media/ubuntu/D2CECE16CECDF2B1/docker/aufs/mnt/b43408232092aae0fd14e859732b4cf680db108932dab332d5a75fe2d4bd61f2-init: invalid argument
```

I've also tried setting the options as follows in /etc/default/docker:
DOCKER_OPTS="-g /cdrom/docker2 --storage-driver=devicemapper"

In the log (/var/log/upstart/docker.log) I see :

```
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: truncate /cdrom/docker2/devicemapper/devicemapper/data: file too large
```

It's odd, because /cdrom (which is the mount for my USB key which contains Ubuntu) has 50GB available:

```
/dev/sdb1        59G  9.1G   50G  16% /cdrom
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248794/run-docker-in-ubuntu-live-disk?rq=1) -- I will have to look into it when I get the chance.

Comment: Tried it - did not work, as explained in the update.

Comment: Does it work (albeit slowly) if you use the "vfs" storage driver? (Which is really no storage driver at all...)

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianMouat -- Unfortunately I get the following error with vfs: Error response from daemon: symlink /proc/mounts /cdrom/docker3/vfs/dir/9034eb7354ade3d329bb795778e098e3d5f1b1b684c0c6a776aa3d057864fdc8-init/etc/mtab: operation not permitted

Comment: @AdrianMouat -- I tried again today using the internal hard disk and vfs, and hello-world worked!  Thanks for the idea.  This solves part of my problem, at least. The hello-world was not slow, but doing a big pull seems to slow my Ubuntu to a crawl, leaving docker-untar processes running.

Comment: Another strange thing happened when I used vfs.  When I did a big pull (only a few 100s of MB in virtual image size but taking up gigabytes of disk), Ubuntu seems to have unmounted the internal hard disk and mounted a virtual disk in its place in the usb key's casper-rw file.  The casper-rw file is the virtual partition limited to 4GB, and it's full after pulling just a couple of the images I need.  Seems I need to either expand the casper partition with a real partition of the USB key or install Ubuntu on a partition of the internal hard disk.

Comment: VFS isn't CoW, so each container will need a full copy of the image - that's probably the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I keep having those errors. Fortunately, I updated the OS to 16.04 as per instruction details from [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

In Ubuntu 14.04 the way of installation leads to errors like above mentioned.
Try this after uninstalling the current version and then

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

For checking run this, run the command `docker run hello-world`. If even after this,  daemon error keep occurring, then refer to the official [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configure-where-the-docker-daemon-listens-for-connections)

Answer (score 0):

**you can use**

```
sudo su
```

or Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix try this command

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu
sudo usermod -aG root ubuntu
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
sudo reboot
```