# Docker: Error creating aufs mounts: Invalid argument (Booting from live usb)

Tags: linux, docker, libusb

I have a Ubuntu setup running off of a live usb device. When I try to run and Docker run commands I get the following error:  Error creating aufs mounts: Invalid argument. Could this be caused from using a live boot? Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run docker in ubuntu live disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248794/run-docker-in-ubuntu-live-disk)

Answer (score 0):

Change /etc/default/docker to have this in it:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper"
```

Look this [Run docker in ubuntu live disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248794/run-docker-in-ubuntu-live-disk)

Comment: docker daemon does not start after this config