# Unable to start docker after configuring hosts in daemon.json

Tags: docker, service, configuration, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to configure docker (version 17.03.1-ce) in ubuntu 16.04 using configuration file */etc/docker/daemon.json* to add an host:

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:1234", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"],
  "dns"  : ["8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"]
}
```

when I try to restart docker.. it fails

```
#service docker restart
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

watching on *systemctl status docker.service*:

```
Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
docker-slave-ubuntu-build dockerd[24806]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: 
the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: 
hosts: (from flag: [fd://], from file: [tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 unix:///var/run/docker.sock])
```

Where I can remove the mentioned flag ? I have to modify maintainer's script ?

Comment: What maintainer script? Can you elaborate on how you installed Docker so someone can try and reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue merging configuration from both the command line and configuration file. The default systemd unit file is specifying `-H fd://` and it conflicts with your `tcp://0.0.0.0:1234` and `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

There are a number of GitHub issues on the subject:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22339
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21559
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25471
- https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/27473

They don't seem to consider this a bug. But it is definitely an annoyance. A workaround is to copy the default unit file and remove the `-H fd://` from it:

```
$ sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/
$ sudo sed -i 's/\ -H\ fd:\/\///g' /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: the copy upfront is a best practice?!

Answer (score 27):

For systemd, my preferred method is to deploy a simple override file (you may need to first create the directory):

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
# Disable flags to dockerd, all settings are done in /etc/docker/daemon.json
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

This removes the `-H ...` default flag from dockerd along with any other options and lets you manage docker from the daemon.json file. This also allows docker to make changes to their startup scripts as long as they don't modify the ExecStart and you'll continue to receive those changes without maintaining your own copy of the docker.service.

After creating this file, run `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart docker`.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to copy `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/` as the default unit is in a built-in directory?

Comment: No, you can override a setting in the /lib service without copying it to /etc. But you do need the empty `ExecStart=` to unset the value so you can reconfigure it.

Answer (score 4):

I found this on the Docker docs and it worked on Docker 18.09.1 and Centos 8:

To work around this problem, create a new file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` with the following contents, to remove the `-H` argument that is used when starting the daemon by default.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

Then reload

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

The reason is:

Docker listens on a socket by default. On Debian and Ubuntu systems using `systemd`, this means that a host flag `-H` is always used when starting `dockerd`. If you specify a `hosts` entry in the `daemon.json`, this causes a configuration conflict (as in the above message) and Docker fails to start.

Here is the link: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/troubleshoot/#troubleshoot-conflicts-between-the-daemonjson-and-startup-scripts

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tried to add both the daemon.json under /etc/docker and a *.conf file under /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d.
It turned out it was enough to have a .conf file only (in my case called override.conf):

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

this way I could expose the docker socket.

Answer (score -1):

I had copied the daemon.json from a website. After running

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
/usr/sbin/dockerd
```

it showed me a better error message that stated that I had a strange invisible character in the daemon.json file