# Docker service hosts config failed to start

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I have Debian 10 virtual machine.
And I want to be able to connect to the docker API from another host.
I can connect to docker from other host if I start docker deamon from console

```
dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://192.168.3.157
```

If I try to configure `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like

```
{
  "hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://192.168.3.157"]
}
```

The command `systemctl start docker` fails. The command `systemctl status docker` have next output

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-11-02 11:32:26 MSK; 1min 10s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 868 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 868 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 02 11:32:24 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 02 11:32:26 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
Nov 02 11:32:26 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Nov 02 11:32:26 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 02 11:32:26 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 02 11:32:26 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 11:32:26 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 02 11:32:53 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 02 11:32:53 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 11:32:53 debian-for-docker systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

How should I configure the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to make my deamon start properly?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.
It's here [Unable to start docker after configuring hosts in daemon.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052054/unable-to-start-docker-after-configuring-hosts-in-daemon-json)
I have created the file /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf with content

```
# Disable flags to dockerd, all settings are done in /etc/docker/daemon.json
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

And then I restarted the service `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart docker`