# Build of docker image with centos:6.6 fails when trying to update repo

Tags: centos, docker

I have the following simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6.6

USER root

RUN yum clean all
RUN yum update
```

And I am trying to build it as usual:

```
docker build -t myimage/hadoop .
```

But I have the following error and I can't find the solution:

> Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base Could not retrieve
>   mirrorlist
>   http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock
>   error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host
>   'mirrorlist.centos.org'" INFO[0005] The command "/bin/sh -c yum
>   update" returned a non-zero code: 1

Any help or reference to solve the problem would be very helpful.

EDIT: I tried the solution given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130536/dockerfile-docker-build-cant-download-packages-centos-yum-debian-ubuntu-ap?rq=1) but with no results.

Comment: The problem is `PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'`. Your DNS is broken.

Comment: The DNS on the host machine? I haven't seen any issue with the host machine. How can I verify if the DNS is broken as you say? The host machine is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The DNS in the container. It is trying to resolve that address and cannot do so. And by broken I may just mean "not configured".

Comment: The problem is that I get this error only my machine, if I try that to another machine it seems to work fine.

Comment: Can you resolve that address on your host machine? I don't know enough about docker to say but it could just be a docker misconfiguration I suppose.

Comment: Looks like your docker networking does not have the access to the web. Anyway, there's too little information to answer the question.

Comment: I am finding that `curl -v http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7\&arch=x86_64\&repo=os\&infra=container` succeeds from the commandline of my build server while `curl -v http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container` fails because the OS splits the url apart by the & characters in the latter instance.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try add "-y" to the ""yum update"?

```sh
RUN yum update -y
```